# Is it acceptable to subscribe someone else to a bug report?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting, community

Launchpad lets you subscribe someone else to a bug report. Occasionally I find a bug closely related to one that Person X is already subscribed to. I therefore think X is likely to be interested in following the new bug, so it makes sense to notify him in this way. On the other hand, spamming X with extra e-mail can be considered poor etiquette.

Is subscribing someone else acceptable? (And if not, then why does Launchpad permit it?) What about subscribing a team to a relevant bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's acceptable--even encouraged--and part of the Ubuntu/FOSS community spirit; it's allowed because we trust ourselves not to frivolously subscribe people to random bugs which may not interest them. The subscribee can always choose to unsubscribe, if necessary. Note that subscribing is restricted to Launchpad users, most of whom presumably have some tangential interest in the software development aspect of Launchpad.

Comment: I look at this feature as a way for the community to make bugs aware to people who may have a way of contributing towards a solution.  If you come across a bug report for **package A**, but it references **package B** and you know the maintainer of **package B**, you may want to alert her of said bug.